# Can I add a Custom field on a Sprint in Redmine?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, redmine, redmine-plugins, redmine-api

I'm using Redmine to develop my app and I need to add a custom field on Sprint. Redmine only allows me to add custom fields on Issues, projects... and not Sprints.

Is there a way to configure it to be able to add a custom field on a Sprint. I am using Redmine Shared API plugin and Scrum Redmine plugin.

**Redmine version**                3.4.6.stable

**Redmine plugins:**

redmine_shared_api             0.0.9

scrum                          0.18.2

Answer (score 0):

Chams - Sprints in context of Redmine are handled using "Target Versions", which in some areas of the system are simply called 'Version'. If you use some Agile plugins, they are most likely using that concept to manage sprints.

So, in order to add a custom field to a sprint, you need to **add a custom fields to a Version**

[image]

After that you won't even have to enable that customer field in you Project's settings. It will be automatically visible on screens such as edit page of a sprint / target version:

[image]